# Find duplicate text strings, then group duplicate rows with common number in adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a giant list of items;

- each row is associated to a unique document number in column A.
- The titles in column B may repeat themselves.
- Column D will contain a group number.

I would like to group the items together, by assigning a group number column D, that already exists in one of the entries.

[image: Example 1]

How do I automate the function represented by the red arrow function? There may be 2+ rows of the same item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula like this:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B2)=0,A2,VLOOKUP(B2,$B$1:D1,3,FALSE))`

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Learning something useful from this. Thank you